# Changing the Email Alert 'from' email address

Tags: email

I currently have an Email Alert setup as the output from a Workflow when a new record is created. This is all working fine.

However, I would like to be able to change the 'from' email address.

It shows my email address, but i dont want to display my email address .

Ideally I would like this to be 'no-reply@my_company_domain'.

How can i acheive this?

Thanks
Shailu

Answer (score 6):

Go here:
Setup > Email Administration > Organization-Wide Email Addresses

You can set up email addresses and make them available to all or specific user profiles. Once verified, the address will be available as a from address for email alerts.

[image]

Also the default user for workflow is configured in workflow>settings

[image]

Since you are the user the user email Id of yours is picked .Instead add a org wide address

[image]

Comment: do you have any idea any possibility of changing from email address of case assignment email notification?

Comment: @Mohit - I don't see workflow & approval setting. Could you please let me know how we can go there? Please mentioned the path.

Comment: @user4567570 It's called Process Automation Settings in Lightning: https://login.salesforce.com/lightning/setup/WorkflowSettings/home